# how to extract variable name from a filename

Tags: filenames

I have data in many files. The file names themselves contain the variables that I need and I am not sure how to extract then, preferably by using csh commands. For example, here is a single file name:

Hourly Data for Andover, NJ - [id=k12n icao, lat=41.0089, lon=-74.7367].csv

The blank spaces are obviously invisible \ symbols (someone was really creative!). Anyway, I need to extract values for variables lat and lon for that filename. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the blank spaces are invisible backslashes? Can you add the actual name of the file in a code block to clarify this?

Comment: It is the actual name of the file I gave above. It contains white spaces that in reality look like: Hourly\ Data\ for\ Andover,\ NJ\ -\ [id=k12n\ icao,\ lat=41.0089,\ lon=-74.7367].csv.  Again - someone was too creative with filenames.

Comment: So you want to get out the `id = k12n icao`, `lat = 41.0089`, and `lon=-74.7367`? Also by `csh` do you mean the shell?